# Connecting to local Linux server from iOS through USB only

Tags: linux, networking, usb, vnc, ios

## What I want to achieve

I have a VNC server running on Linux laptop and I want to connect to it from my old iPad 3 running iOS 9 (kinda a second screen). The problem is that it can't connect to WiFi at home, and the laptop is not connected through Ethernet which means I cannot just create an access point without losing access to the outer world. So I want to use something like usbmuxd to set up a connection from iOS to Linux using USB cable

## What I tried

I've looked into the usbmuxd thing and it really works good, but in the opposite direction: tools like iproxy and inetcat forward connections to a listening port on iDevice while I need to allow connections to ports on this same machine

## About iSH

I'm using iSH on a newer iPhone to quickly test things using nc aka netcat. I think it might be possible to make what I want using some weird combination on these commands on both devices, but again the final goal is utilizing iPad which is too old for apps like iSH